# Query Intercom.IO API for subset of users by a subpriority of a priority of the User instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, intercom

I'd like to query the API for my Intercom.io app and get a subset of users that have a specific nested key value pair.

The client.users.listBy() works but only for keys that are a direct property of the user object, for instance client.users.listBy({ email: someUsersEmail@domain.com }) works just fine because email is a property directly on the user instance.

My user data is structured like this

```
user = {
  ...
  email: someUsersEmail@domain.com,
  ...,
  customer_attributes: {
    ...,
    affiliate_code: 'someAffiliateCode',
    ...
  },
  ...  
}
```

and I would like to find all the users that have customer_attributes.affilate_code equal to affiliate_code: 'someAffiliateCode'.
I'd like to query the API like this:

```
client.users.listBy({customer_attributes.affiliate_code: 'someAffiliateCode'}, function(err, resp) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(resp)
})
```

But I'm getting this error

```
client.users.listBy({customer_attributes.affiliate_code: 'onetouch'}, function(err, resp) {
                                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Does anyone know how I can query the Intercom API for nested Key value pairs like in the way described above? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As the interpreter hints, that "." in the key name is not valid JavaScript.

The only way to accomplish what you are looking for is to pre-define a Segment in the Intercom UI with "affiliate_code = onetouch". Then you can programmatically list users using that Segment ID. https://developers.intercom.io/reference#list-by-tag-segment-company

```
client.users.listBy({ segment_id: 'foo' }, callback);
```